# Is auto-chunking enabled by default when GZIP compression is used in the HDF5 C++ api?

Tags: python, c++, hdf5, h5py, hdf

I am writing an HDF5 file using the C++ HDF api and performing a few comparisons against the H5py Python library.

In the H5py Python library [autochunking](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-and-hdf5/9781491944981/ch04.html) is applied by default when a compression algorithm such as GZIP or LZF is used.

Does the same condition apply to the HDF5 C++ api?  If so, how can I prove that chunks were automatically created when a compression algorithm, such as GZIP,  was applied to the data sets.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/compression.html:

> To apply a compression filter to a dataset it must be created with a chunked dataset storage layout.

And you have to do it manually:

```
1. Create a dataset creation property list and modify it to enable chunking and compression.
2. Create the dataset.
```